# Distributed computing using java RMI and CORBA

Tags: java, rmi, distributed-computing, corba

following is the problem i am facing. i will explain it will an example

If there is an IT department that makes use of Java RMI and another department which make use of CORBA, if i happened to integrate those two departments

1. spending least amount of time
2. with least budget

what are the approaches I can take

could someone help me to find an answer for this question. I really appreciate any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fear spending the least amount of time *together* with the least budget together will be counter-productive (if that's what you mean).

Since Java has a native CORBA implementation, you should be able to put together a gateway service simply by referencing the IDL definitions from the CORBA projects.

Comment: And it doesn't involve using (yet another) third party API.

Answer (score 1):

Consider [Hessian](http://hessian.caucho.com/).